# How can I complete disable Google Hangouts from all devices?

Tags: google-hangouts

How can I complete disable Hangouts in my Google account?

I want to close Hangouts, without disabling my entire Google account. I don't want anyone to be able to message me. If anyone tries to message me, I want them to receive some sort of message saying that I don't have Hangouts enabled.

Is there a way to do this?

I don't want to just uninstall Hangouts on my device, because that might not be enough for my contacts to realise that I am not on Hangouts, I want my contacts to know that I have disabled Hangouts.

Answer (score -1):

From [Remove products](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/81987?hl=en)

> You can remove certain products from your Google Account at any time. To remove a product you no longer use, follow the steps below.
>
> ### Computer
>
> 1. Open your [Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/).
> 2. In the "Account preferences" section, select **Delete your account or services**.
> 3. Choose **Delete products**. You might need to sign in.
> 4. Next to the product you want to remove, select Remove [image: Remove].
>
> To remove a product from your account that isn't listed in your Google Account, visit [support.google.com](https://support.google.com/) for more info on a specific product.